# Subset a dataframe based on a single condition applied to multiple columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I've had a look through the existing subset Q&A's on this site and couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

I want to subset a data frame based on one condition (e.g. if the value is below 5). However, I only want the rows where the value in all of the columns is below 5.

For example using the `iris` dataset - I would like to select all the rows where columns 1-3 all have values below 5.

```
subdata <- iris[which(iris[,1:3]<5),]
```

This doesn't do it for me. I get lots of NA rows at the bottom of the subset data.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
subdata <- iris[apply(iris[,1:3] < 5, 1, all),]
```

Comment: Out of interest, what does the `1` do in between `<5` and `all`?

Comment: It tells `apply` to run the function `all` (which is basically a logical AND) for each row of `iris[,1:3] < 5`. See `?apply` - it is very useful in `R`.