# Subset dataframe based on statistical range of each column

Tags: r, subset, apply, sapply

I would like to subset a dataframe by selecting only columns that exceed a specific range. IE, I would like to evaluate max-min for each column individually and select only columns whose range is greater than a given value. For example, given the following simple dataframe, I would like to create a subset dataframe that only contains columns with a range > 99. (Columns b an c.)

```
d <- data.frame(a=seq(0,10,1),b=seq(0,100,10),c=seq(0,200,20))
```

I have tried modifying the example here: [Subset a dataframe based on a single condition applied to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068408/subset-a-dataframe-based-on-a-single-condition-applied-to-multiple-columns), but have had no luck. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply()` to apply function to each column of `d` and then calculate difference for range of column values. Then compare it to 99. As result you will get TRUE or FALSE and then use it to subset columns.

```
d[,sapply(d,function(x) diff(range(x))>99)]
```